# Void cast to type

Tags: c++, mfc

I have MFC dialog based application.

```
void CThr_MfcDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    this->SetWindowTextW(L"bla");
    (CThr_MfcDlg*)GetDlgItem(IDD_THR_MFC_DIALOG)->SetWindowText(L"hello") ;

}
```

Line `this->SetWindowTextW(L"bla");` changes form caption to `bla`

I expect line `(CThr_MfcDlg*)GetDlgItem(IDD_THR_MFC_DIALOG)->SetWindowText(L"hello") ;` should change caption to `hello`, but have compile error:

```
Error   1   error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'void' to 'CThr_MfcDlg *'
```

Comment: Try `((CThr_MfcDlg*)GetDlgItem(IDD_THR_MFC_DIALOG))->...`

Comment: Ask yourself why `(CThr_MfcDlg*)` is present in this code *at all*. [`CWnd::GetDlgItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/77d16yhw.aspx) return a `CWnd*`, which supports [`CWnd::SetWindowText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhczy8bz.aspx).

Comment: +1 to offset downvote. I think it's not a bad question since beginners can easily make this mistake.

Comment: @ikh I didn't down vote this, but which mistake are you referring to? The improper, and improperly *applied*, C-style cast?, Or the fact that no cast is required in this in the first place? Its probably also worth noting that unless the dialog this is wrapping as a child window *of itself*, this is a null-pointer-dereference just waiting to explode anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm saying about operator precedence. Beginners can easily forget it >o<

Comment: Stop using C-style casts and this problem goes away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Since -> operator's precedence (2) is higher than cast operator's (3), your code is parsed in this way:

```
(CThr_MfcDlg*) (GetDlgItem(IDD_THR_MFC_DIALOG)->SetWindowText(L"hello")) ;
```

To avoid this, you should use parenthesis with casting.

```
// this will be correct.
((CThr_MfcDlg*)GetDlgItem(IDD_THR_MFC_DIALOG))->SetWindowText(L"hello");
```

Comment: Syntactically correct, but I somehow prefer WhozCraig's solution. ;-)

Comment: @DevSolar Of course. but I think mine is a proper question to OP's question. The question contain not only `SetWindowText`-ing, but *operator precedence*, which I think OP should know.